# I cannot locate /var/lib/mlocate.db

Tags: ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS installed on my Raspberry Pi and I try to locate the file /var/lib/mlocate.db but I cannot find it.

I installed locate package.

It's because I'm doing an online course from Linux Professional Institute and I read this passage:

> One problem with locate is that it only shows entries present in the
> database generated by updatedb (located in /var/lib/mlocate.db). If
> the database is outdated, the output could show files that have been
> deleted since the last time it was updated. One way to avoid this is
> to add the -e parameter, which will make it check to see if the file
> still exists before showing it on the output.

So I would like to see the database.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: Did you install the `locate` program? (`sudo apt install mlocate`)

Comment: @Bobo yes I installed locate package.